# jquery - if href attr == ""

Tags: jquery, if-statement, href, attr

I am trying to find out if a href attr is empty do something, my code is as follows...

```
jQuery('#sidebar a').click(function() {

     var bob = jQuery(this).attr("href");

     if(jQuery(bob).attr() == "") {
            alert('I am empty href value');
        }

    });
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong? Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: You forgot `"href"` in `attr()`

Answer (score 8):

You're passing `bob` into `jQuery` as a selector. Just test it directly:

```
jQuery('#sidebar a').click(function() {

    var bob = jQuery(this).attr("href");

    if (bob == "") {
        alert('I am empty href value');
    }

});
```

Or better yet, just:

```
    if (!bob) {
```

[Gratuitous live example](http://jsbin.com/ifuyik)

Answer (score 3):

You are setting a variable and then never checking it. Personally, I wouldn't even create a variable; Just do the check.

```
jQuery('#sidebar a').click(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).attr("href") == "") {
        alert('I am empty href value');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use this instead

```
jQuery('#sidebar a').click(function() {

 var bob = jQuery(this).attr("href");

 if(bob === "") {
        alert('I am empty href value');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer is already given by great guys.

just check
    if(bob=="")

I would add one more line. Just for safety you can trim bob using jQuery.

```
bob = jQuery.trim(bob);
```

This will make the validity a bit stronger.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('#sidebar a').click(function() {

     if(jQuery(this).attr("href")==""){
            alert('I am empty href value');
        }

    });
```

There is no use of filtering your bob again with jQuery. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the attribute `href` to variable `bob` already. Just use:

```
bob == ""
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, that's a great help. I see the error of my ways now.

Comment: @Phil Make sure you accept the answer that you feel answered your question.